# Prove that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{5^i}\right) >3/4$

Tags: infinite-product

Prove that $$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{5^i}\right) >\frac34.$$

Any hint?

Comment: Anything attempted?

Comment: Is there any closed form for this?

Comment: @ProtectedSource: in terms of the $\text{QPochhammer}$ symbol, but that is kind of tautological and it is not an elementary function.

Comment: Here's something to try: take a logarithm to convert the product to a sum.  Some work is needed to estimate the individual terms suitably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{5^i}\right)\geq 1-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{5^i}>1-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^i}.$$
You may show the first inequality by induction.

Comment: Indeed to justify the first inequality, you can note that multiplying a number less than 1 by a factor 1−p decreases it by at most p.